# Gruvbox colorscheme not applying

Tags: linux, neovim

So, I tried applying gruvbox color scheme in neovim.
But I'm getting errors saying it can't find gruvbox color scheme.
There is code:

```
set termguicolors
let g:gruvbox_contrast_dark='medium'
let g:gruvbox_contrast_light='hard'
colorscheme gruvbox
hi LspCxxHlGroupMemberVariable guifg=#83a598
```

and snippet of plugins.lua:

```
return require('packer').startup(function()
  use 'morhetz/gruvbox'
end)
```

I tried adding:
g:gruvbox_termcolors=256

But it didn't work.

Error:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'gruvbox'

Comment: Did you try loading it with Plug: `Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'`?

Comment: No, i will try that.

Comment: Hint: plugins added via packer `use` has to be installed. That is, everytime you update your packer plugin config, make sure you run `PackerSync` command. Make sure you have read the [packer quickstart guide](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim#quickstart).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

would be great if you can share you config with us so we can help you, I'm also using gruvbox but without a problem. Here is some of steps that you can do, I assume you have using lua for your config.

plugin: https://github.com/ellisonleao/gruvbox.nvim

after you add plugin to packer startup fun, run this command to be sure that  plugin is installed :PackerSync

after that go into your init.lua file and pass this line of code

```
vim.o.background = "dark" #you can use dark or light mode.

vim.cmd([[colorscheme gruvbox]])
```

this should help you to make gruvbox to work.